# Failing to run hello-world example on sky tmote

Tags: contiki

I'm trying to run the hello-world example in contiki on a sky tmote. I'm using ubuntu and followed this tutorial: http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html#hardware

The first time I executed:

```
make TARGET=sky hello-world.upload
```

it worked fine but I got an error when executing:

```
make TARGET=sky login

../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux -b115200 
make: execvp: ../../tools/sky/serialdump-linux: Permission denied
make: *** [login] Error 127
```

And now from now on every time I execute

```
make TARGET=sky hello-world.upload
```

I get the output from the tutorial (the note)

```
make z1-reset z1-upload
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world'
make -k -j 20 z1-reset-sequence
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world'
Done
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world'
make -j 20 z1-upload-sequence
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world'
Done
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world'
rm hello-world.ihex
```

Before I once tried the instantcontiki with the VMPlayer and when this occured I just had to reconnect the sky mote again via a button in the VMPlayer, but since I'm not using it anymore I don't know what to do.

Also I couldn't figure out how to solve the Error 127 from above.

Greetings,
Jan

PS: I'm new to linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which worked at me:

Find out at which USB is your tmote connected, e.g. USB0 and than just run:

sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0

Answer (score 0):

this phrase `permission denied` indicates that you are not the owner, ie. you are not the root

use `sudo su`,
give your password for the root
and repeat the code.

you will not find the error